# Running other docker images in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having some issues running some Docker image via Jenkins job.

A little bit about my system:

I have a Virtual machine (Ubuntu) where the following services are running:

- **Docker**:

```
patrikas@xxx-test:~$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
```

- **Gitlab** (We host our own private Gitlab server)

```
Version:        16.9.2
Revision:       8443896c867
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     PostgreSQL
DB Version:     13.13
URL:            https://xxx-test.test.lt
HTTP Clone URL: https://xxx-test.test.lt/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@xxx-test.test.lt:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: yes
```

- **Jenkins**

```
patrikas@xxx-test:~$ jenkins --version
2.440.1
```

**Note:**
I have also added jenkins to docker group using the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

Additionally, I have installed **Docker Pipeline** and **Docker plugin** plugins on Jenkins:
[image]

I have integrated Jenkins with one of my Gitlab repositories and that seems to work fine. On my repository, I have created a Jenkinsfile with the following script:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'espressif/idf:v5.0.4' } }
      stages {
        stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'idf.py build'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-docker-image.html

As you can see from above, I am trying to run a espressif/idf docker image and I am executing `idf.py build` to build my application.

I am trying to execute a Jenkins job via the Jenkins control panel but I am getting the following error:

```
Started by user Lukas
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/caches/git-221913a41419ad953cacdca7e55ae5d6/.git # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines
 > git config remote.origin.url https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Gitlab_auth_UNPW
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/main
Seen branch in repository origin/test
Seen 3 remote branches
Obtained Jenkinsfile from b3121d3001e4394bb582f025f191db31e48b9ea4
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential 4f166f7c-da3e-4455-a42c-4e53b689925e
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Gitlab_auth_UNPW
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b3121d3001e4394bb582f025f191db31e48b9ea4 (main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b3121d3001e4394bb582f025f191db31e48b9ea4 # timeout=10
Commit message: " change: Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 39953433441d493cc123634ea5410dc2fd2a9877 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . espressif/idf:v5.0.4
.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 116:120 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** espressif/idf:v5.0.4 cat
$ docker top 19e7b4ffae40f6e966deb15e18a062606c0ca5d47ac1d23e8a9de92259b645e7 -eo pid,comm
ERROR: The container started but didn't run the expected command. Please double check your ENTRYPOINT does execute the command passed as docker run argument, as required by official docker images (see https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency for entrypoint consistency requirements).
Alternatively you can force image entrypoint to be disabled by adding option `--entrypoint=''`.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ idf.py build
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Jenkins_pipeline_main@tmp/durable-92e61232/script.sh.copy: 1: idf.py: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 19e7b4ffae40f6e966deb15e18a062606c0ca5d47ac1d23e8a9de92259b645e7
$ docker rm -f --volumes 19e7b4ffae40f6e966deb15e18a062606c0ca5d47ac1d23e8a9de92259b645e7
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

What could be the cause why Jenkins cannot run the docker image? Am I missing something? I appreciate if so